# Combine dialog and wizard in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog, wizard

I need to create multiple steps dialog with next, back, cancel and submit buttons.
I tried to use wizard within empty dialog, but it's just don't have the look and fill of a dialog.

1. Is it the right way to put wizard in an empty dialog?
2. Does jQuery have other component to that (I didn't find one)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of

1) Jquery plugins ( [link1](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/slideshow/) , [link2](http://jquery.malsup.com/) etc)

2) Or Do from the scratch ([link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442964/html-form-over-several-slides))